# c++ password storage .txt file + masking input

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to programming - just starting out with C++. So I wanted to make an application - just for fun - which would mask user input with asterisks. I did some research and found exactly what I was looking for. As you can see inside the code below it works fine but only checks password from a char I put - "correct_password". I thought it'd be more challenging to extend options. The program would write two options out: 1. register - just put your login and password (without asterisks), then store it into a file (fstream I guess), 2. login - after putting login and password (with asterisks just the way it is in getpass) it would check the file for data if user is actually registered. Even thought maybe about encrypting data in that file, although I have no idea how to proceed. Well, it's just made up thing to learn some new stuff, I know it's not really a THING and there's no really a purpose to write such code - just messing around with C++. Maybe you got some ideas how to snap that? After I wrote this asterisk thing i don't really see where I should put those other options, storing in file and so on. Would love to go through some ideas and appreciate the input from more experienced coders :)

I tried using fstream inside getpass but didn't work out. Generally I'd like to  extend this program with login and password input, storing them into .txt file and then program would check if user is registered and while logging with this data input would be masked with asterisks - just like my first idea of that program which is only masking password input. I don't really know how to split unmasked input with that inside getpass.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

string getpass(const char *dat, bool s_asterisk=true)
{
  const char BACKSPACE=8;
  const char RETURN=13;

  string password;
  unsigned char ch=0;

  cout << dat;

  DWORD con_mode;
  DWORD dwRead;

  HANDLE hIn=GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

  GetConsoleMode( hIn, &con_mode );
  SetConsoleMode( hIn, con_mode & ~(ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT | ENABLE_LINE_INPUT) );

  while(ReadConsoleA( hIn, &ch, 1, &dwRead, NULL) && ch !=RETURN)
    {
       if(ch==BACKSPACE)
         {
            if(password.length()!=0)
              {
                 if(s_asterisk)
                     cout <<"\b \b";
                 password.resize(password.length()-1);
              }
         }
       else
         {
             password+=ch;
             if(s_asterisk)
                 cout <<'*';
         }
    }
  cout << endl;
  return password;
}



int main()
{
  const char *correct_password="fdsidfjsijdsf21128321873";

    START:

  string password=getpass("Enter the password: ",true);
  if(password==correct_password){
      cout <<"\nCorrect password."<<endl;
      exit(1);
  }else{
      cout <<"\nIncorrect password. Try again.\n"<<endl;
      goto START;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually you don't want to store actual passwords in a file. Although encrypting them would help security (to at least some degree), it's still generally pretty insecure and better avoided.

What you usually want to do instead is salt the password, then hash the salted password with a cryptographic hash. Then you store the salt and the hash, rather than the password itself.

Then (for the simplest case) when the user wants to log in, you repeat the same process: retrieve the salt for their password, apply the salt to the password they enter, hash the result, and finally compare that result to the value you stored. If they match, you assume the user entered the correct password. If they don't match, you know they didn't.

Note that this is only reasonable for the user logging into your application locally (or at least over a secure connection). If they might log in over an insecure connection, you need to get considerably more sophisticated still.

Another major point though: nearly all of this should happen *outside* `getpass`. `getpass` should do exactly one thing: read in a password from the user. Salting, hashing, storing, and so on, should all happen separately from that.